# Javascript pass get params

Tags: javascript

I get exists get params on request:

```
?filterBy=1,2,3
```

How I can pass params after filterBy with js?

My solution:

```
switch(type) {
        case 'status':
            window.location.href = '?filter-status=i=' + filters;
        break;
        case 'oldFrom':
            window.location.href = '?oldFrom';
        break;
        case 'oldTo':
            window.location.href = '?oldTo';
        break;
        case 'newFrom':
            window.location.href = '?newFrom';
        break;
        case 'newTo':
            window.location.href = '?newTo';
        break;
        case 'catesel':
            window.location.href = '?byCategory=' + filters;
        break;
    }
```

In my case I rewrite get params. 
Example: if I have exists param on request: `byCategory=1,2,3` And when I click button to add new filter by request is remove and write new. How I can do this:

`?byCategory=1,2,3&newFrom` ...

I need remove `window.location.href` or how pass exists get params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting params from your url, use URL constructor:

```
const url = new URL("?filterBy=1,2,3");
const filterBy = url.searchParams.get("filterBy");
console.log(filterBy);
```

If you need to get array of values, just split it into array

```
const myArrOfFilters = filterBy.split(',');
console.log(myArrOfFilters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `URLSearchParams` to get query string values

```
var params = '';
var type = 'status';
var filters = '1,2';

switch (type) {
 case 'status':
  params = '?filter-status-i=' + filters;
  break;
 case 'oldFrom':
  params = '?oldFrom';
  break;
 case 'oldTo':
  params = '?oldTo';
  break;
 case 'newFrom':
  params = '?newFrom';
  break;
 case 'newTo':
  params = '?newTo';
  break;
 case 'catesel':
  params = '?byCategory=' + filters;
  break;
}
//window.location.href = params
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
console.log(urlParams.get('filter-status-i'));
```